# What's the best option for a framework-agnostic Ruby background worker library?

Tags: ruby, backgroundworker, amqp, daemons

I'm building a simple recipe search engine with Ruby and Sinatra for an iPhone app, using RabbitMQ for my message queue.  I'm looking around and finding a lot of different implementation choices for background processes, but most of them either implement custom message queue algorithms or operate as Rails plugins.

What's out there in terms of high-quality framework-agnostic worker libraries that will play nicely with RabbitMQ?

And are there any best-practices I should keep in mind while writing the worker code, beyond the obvious:

```
# BAD, don't do this!
begin
  # work
rescue Exception
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing [my own library](http://github.com/sporkmonger/chaingang/tree/master) in a fit of uncontrollable yak-shaving.  Daemon kit was the right general idea, but seriously way too heavyweight for my needs.  I don't want what looks like a full rails app for each of my daemons.  I'm going to end up with at least 3 daemons, and that would be a colossal mess of directories.  The daemons gem has a horrible API, and while I was tempted to abstract it away, I realized it was probably easier to just manage the fork myself, so that's what I did.

API looks like this:

```
require "rubygems"
require "chaingang"

class Worker
  def setup
    # Set up connections here
  end

  def teardown
    # Tear down connections here
  end

  def call
    # Do some work
    sleep 1
  end
end
ChainGang.prepare(Worker.new)
```

And then you just use the included rake task to start/stop/restart or check status.  I took a page from the Rack playbook: anything that implements the `call` method is fair game as an argument to ChainGang.prepare and ChainGang.work methods, so a `Proc` is a valid worker object.

Took me longer to build than it would've to use something else, but I have a vague suspicion that it'll pay off in the long-run.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Beanstalk and have written my own daemons using the [daemons gem](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/). [Daemon kit](http://github.com/kennethkalmer/daemon-kit/tree/master) is a new project but queue loops are not yet implemented. You can also have a look at [Nanite](http://github.com/ezmobius/nanite/tree/master) if it fits your needs, it's framework-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Check out nanite (written in Ruby), it's a young project written atop rabbitmq.

github.com/ezmobius/nanite/tree/master